# If my data follows a normal distribution, does that mean my residual are normally distributed as well?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, residuals

I have a data set which approximately follows a normal distribution. Does that necessarily mean that the residuals (as define) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals)) of my dataset do follow a normal distribution?

Answer (score 4):

Clearly not. Imagine a case, where you have a two groups, one with a half normal distribution on the positive axis and one on the negative axis. If the groups are about the same size that results in an overall normal distribution.

Methods such as linear regression only make assumptions on the residuals, so that looking at anything else is not that useful. For moderate to large sample sizes some deviations from normality for the residuals are not an issue,  either.

In practice I suspect that something vaguely normal looking for the overall distribution is a good sign though.

Comment: In the linear model, once you assume a distribution on the residuals you also assume a distribution on y (the same distribution to be precise)

Comment: So  it means that a non normal distribution may have a normal residuals ?

Comment: @user3841581 Sure, in the sense that the residuals are only normal after taking into account the factors and covariates in the model. E.g. you could have two groups in your data that each follow a normal distribution with the same variance, but with different means. In that case when you plot the overall data you have a bimodal distribution (clearly not normal), but the residuals are wonderfully normal once you have accounted for the two groups in your model.

Comment: @Repmat the conditional distribution of $y$ is the same as the conditional distribution of the errors, but the *marginal* distribution of $y$ depends on the distribution of the predictors.

Comment: @Glen_b the example in the answer was meant to be one with a marginal distribution that is normal,  but very non-normal residuals.

Comment: @Björn My apologies, you did do that.